# ¿ Como hacer que el logo ocupe todo el alto de la barra de navegación?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

estoy tratando de que logo de la barra de navegación ocupe todo el alto de esta, sin conseguirlo.
He probado varias formas y siempre me queda margen arriba, lo que hace que si aumento el tamaño, haga la barra más alta.
He visto ejemplos ya realizados y en este caso no se que paso por alto.
Mi intención era que ocupará todo el alto de la barra de navegación si interferir en el resto de elementos de esta.
Muestro el código que estoy empleando.
Gracias.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700,900);
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ek+Mukta:400,600,700');
*{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}
#logo{
 /*background: url(../img/milogo2.png);*/
 float:none;
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   top: -5px;
 margin-left: 0%;
  } 

/*#logo{
 top: 0;
 height:100%;
}*/

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Ek Mukta', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
    color: #666;
    background-color: #fff;
 font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
 font-weight: 400;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 38px;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 36px;
}
h3 {
 font-size: 32px;
}
h4 {
 font-size: 28px;
}
h5 {
 font-size: 24px;
}
h6 {
 font-size: 20px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
 color: #111;
}

h1.h-xlight,h2.h-xlight,h3.h-xlight ,h4.h-xlight ,h5.h-xlight ,h6.h-xlight  {
 font-weight: 200;
}

h1.h-light,h2.h-light,h3.h-light ,h4.h-light ,h5.h-light ,h6.h-light  {
 font-weight: 300;
}

h1.h-bold,h2.h-bold,h3.h-bold ,h4.h-bold ,h5.h-bold ,h6.h-bold  {
 font-weight: 600;
}

h1.font-light,h2.font-light,h3.font-light,h4.font-light,h5.font-light,h6.font-light {
 color: #fff;
}

.big-heading {
 font-size: 48px;
 font-weight: 700;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 20px;

}

p.lead {
 font-weight: 600;
}

.highlight-light {
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
 padding: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 color: #111;
}

.highlight-dark {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 padding: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 color: #fff;
}

.highlight-color {
 padding: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
}

a {
    color: #666;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

blockquote {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #999;
}

blockquote.bg-light {
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
 padding: 20px;
 color: #222;
}

blockquote.bg-dark {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 padding: 20px;
}

blockquote strong {
  font-weight: 700;
}




.light {
    font-weight: 400;
}

/* --- logo --- */
.site-logo {
 margin-top: 0px;
}
/*.site-logo a.brand {
 color: #111;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 32px;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 900;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
*/

/* ------- Navigation ------------ */
#navigation {
 background: #fff;
 z-index: 9999;
 width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
 box-shadow:0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}


.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-weight: 700;
}


.navbar-brand:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.nav.navbar-nav {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse .nav.navbar-nav {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}


.navbar-custom ul.nav li a {
 font-size: 12px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #444;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse ul.nav li a {
     -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 color: #fff;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu {
   border-radius: 0; 
 margin-top: 21px;
 border-top: none;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav li a:hover ul.dropdown-menu {
     -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}


.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;

}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li:last-child{
 border-bottom: none;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a {
 padding: 10px 20px;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
 background: #fefefe;
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a {
 color: #666;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a {
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav li.active {
    outline: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav li.active {
    outline: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}

.navbar-toggle {
    padding: 4px 6px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-toggle:active {
    outline: 0;
}


/* misc */
hr {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

hr.bold {
  border-top: 3px solid #eee;
}

.divider-header {
 display: block;
 width: 40px;
 height: 2px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.divider-short {
 display: block;
 width: 60px;
 height: 5px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* margins */
.marginbot-0{margin-bottom:0 !important;}
.marginbot-10{margin-bottom:10px !important;}
.marginbot-20{margin-bottom:20px !important;}
.marginbot-30{margin-bottom:30px !important;}
.marginbot-40{margin-bottom:40px !important;}
.marginbot-50{margin-bottom:50px !important;}
.marginbot-60{margin-bottom:60px !important;}
.marginbot-70{margin-bottom:70px !important;}
.marginbot-80{margin-bottom:80px !important;}
.marginbot-90{margin-bottom:90px !important;}
.marginbot-100{margin-bottom:100px !important;}

.margintop-0{margin-top:0 !important;}
.margintop-10{margin-top:10px !important;}
.margintop-20{margin-top:20px !important;}
.margintop-30{margin-top:30px !important;}
.margintop-40{margin-top:40px !important;}
.margintop-45{margin-top:45px !important;}
.margintop-50{margin-top:50px !important;}

/* ===========================
--- General sections
============================ */

.home-section {
    padding-top: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 110px;
 display:block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:120;
}

.inner-section {
    padding-top: 110px;
    padding-bottom: 110px;
}


.home-section.nopadd-bot {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}


.section-heading h2 {
 font-size: 24px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.section-heading p {
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 1.6em;
}

.color-dark .section-heading h2 {
 color: #111;
}
.color-dark .section-heading p {
 color: #444;
}

.color-dark .divider-short {
 background: #666;
}
.color-dark .divider-header {
 background: #666;
}

.color-light .divider-short {
 background: #666;
}
.color-light .divider-header {
 background: #666;
}


.color-light .section-heading h2 {
 color: #fff;
}
.color-light .section-heading p {
 color: #fefefe;
}

.color-light blockquote,.color-light p {
 color: #fefefe;
}

/* --- section bg var --- */

.bg-white {
 background: #fff;
}

.bg-gray {
 background: #f9f9f9;
}


.bg-dark {
 background: #404040;
}

/* --- section color var --- */

.text-light {
 color: #fff;
}



/* ===========================
--- Intro
============================ */

.hero { background: url(http://i63.tinypic.com/vsgaon.jpg) no-repeat center center; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; padding: 200px 0 200px 0; height: auto; }
.hero h1 { font-size: 40px; letter-spacing: 12px; margin: 40px 0 10px; font-weight: 900; color: #fff;}
.hero h1 span { color: #a1a9b0; display: inline-block; }
.hero p { font-size: 24px; font-weight: 400; color: #fefefe; }
.learn-more-btn { background: rgba(61, 201, 179, 1); padding: 20px 40px; border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -o-border-radius: 5px; color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 1px; display: inline-block; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #309383; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #309383; box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #309383; margin: 60px 0 0; font-weight: bold; }
.learn-more-btn:hover, .learn-more-btn:focus { background: rgba(61, 201, 179, 0.6); color: #fff; }



.intro {
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 padding:0;
}
.intro-inner {
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 padding:120px 0 20px;
}

.brand-heading {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.intro-text {
    font-size: 18px;
}


/* Carousel Styles */

.carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 650px;
}

.carousel-control {
    width: 0;
}

.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right {
 opacity: 1;
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 background-image: none;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 text-shadow: none;
}

.carousel-control.left span {
 padding: 0;
}

.carousel-control.right span {
 padding: 0;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, 
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right, 
.carousel-control .icon-prev, 
.carousel-control .icon-next {
 position: absolute;
 top: 45%;
 z-index: 5;
 display: inline-block;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
.carousel-control .icon-prev {
 left: 30px;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right,
.carousel-control .icon-next {
 right: 30px;
}



.carousel-control.left span:hover,
.carousel-control.right span:hover {
 opacity: .7;
 filter: alpha(opacity=70);
}

.carousel-inner > .item {
  margin-left:0;
  margin-top:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left:0;
  padding-left: 0;
}


/* Carousel Header Styles */
.header-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 1.8%;
    right: auto;
    width: 96.66666666666666%;
    color: #fff;
}

.header-text h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.header-text h2 span {
 padding: 10px;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header-text h3 span {
 color: #fff;
}

.btn-min-block {
    min-width: 170px;
    line-height: 26px;
}

.btn-theme {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.btn-theme:hover {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
}

/* ===========================
--- About
============================ */




/* ===========================
--- Services
============================ */
.service-box {
 background: #fff;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #f7f7f7;
 padding: 40px 20px;
}

.service-box:hover {
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 margin-top: -20px;
}

.service-icon {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
} 

.service-desc h5 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #666;
 font-size: 18px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.service-desc .divider-header {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/* ===========================
--- Works
============================ */

#owl-works {

}

.item {
    margin: 10px;
}

.item img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
} 

/* ===========================
--- Contact
============================ */


.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

form#contact-form .form-group label {
 text-align: left !important;
 display: block;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 16px;
}
form#contact-form input,form#contact-form select,form#contact-form textarea {
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 1.6em;
 border: 1px solid #eee;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow:  none;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

.btn-lg,
.btn-group-lg > .btn {
  border-radius: 2px;
}

form#contact-form input:focus,form#contact-form select:focus,form#contact-form textarea:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
.input-group-addon {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

.widget-contact {
 text-align: left;
}



/* ===========================
--- Bottom
============================ */

.boxcol-25 {
 width: 100%;
}

.box-social {
 list-style: none;
}

.box-social li {
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
}


.box-social .social-facebook a { 
 display: block;
 background: #3873ae;
}


/* ==== Sidebar ==== */
.sidebar .widget h5 {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 700;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.sidebar .widget {
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.widget ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin-left:0;
 padding-left:0;
}
.sidebar .widget ul li {
 margin-left:0;
 padding-left:0;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.sidebar .widget ul li a {
 color: #666;
}


.widget.widget_categories ul li:before {
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: 'Pe-icon-7-stroke';
 speak: none;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 text-transform: none;
 line-height: 1;

 /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 content: "\e684";
 margin-right: 10px;
}


.widget.widget_recent_post ul li figure {
 float: left;
 margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.widget.widget_recent_post ul li {
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.widget.widget_recent_post ul li:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.widget.widget_recent_post ul li h6 {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.widget.widget_recent_post ul li span {
 font-size: 14px;
}

.widget .tagcloud a {
 padding: 4px 10px;
 color: #fff;
 display:inline-block;
 margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
 font-size: 14px;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

.widget .tagcloud a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 background: #333;
}

/* --- widget --- */

form.search-form input {
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 1.6em;
 border: 1px solid #eee;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow:  none;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

form.search-form input:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}



/* ===========================
--- Footer
============================ */

footer {
    background-color: #404040;
}

footer {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 50px 0 30px ;
 
}

footer p {
 color: #f8f8f8;
 font-size: 14px;
}

footer a.totop {
 color: #fff;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
footer a.totop:focus {
 outline: 0;
}



/* menu */
ul.footer-menu {
 list-style: none;
}

ul.footer-menu li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0 0 0 10px;

}

ul.footer-menu li a {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding-left: 9px;
 line-height: 1.1em;
}

ul.footer-menu li:first-child a {
 border-left: none;
 padding-left: 0;
}

.social-widget {
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.social-widget ul li a:hover {
 color: #fff;
}

footer .social-widget ul.team-social li a {
 margin: 0 5px;
}

/* === testimonial slide === */
.testimonialslide {
 margin-top:0;
 padding-top: 0;
}

.testimonialslide ul li blockquote {
 color: #fff;
 border-left: none;
}

.testimonialslide ul li h4 {
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 900;
}
.testimonialslide ul li h4 span {
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 400;
}


/* --- button --- */
.btn {
 border-radius: 2px;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 outline: none;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-weight: 400; 
 text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 font-size: 14px;
}

.btn.btn-noradius {
 border-radius: 0;
}

a.btn:focus{
 outline: 0;
}

.btn-red {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #c83539;
  border-color: #c83539;
}
.btn-red:hover,
.btn-red:focus,
.btn-red:active,
.btn-red.active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #666;
  border-color: #666;
}
.btn-red:active {
  background-image: none;
}


.btn-skin:hover,
.btn-skin:focus,
.btn-skin:active,
.btn-skin.active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #666;
  border-color: #666;
}


.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus {
    border: 1px solid #28c3ab;
    outline: 0;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #28c3ab;
}

.btn-huge {
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 26px;
}

.banner-social-buttons {
    margin-top: 0;
}

/* --- progress --- */
.progress {
  height: 40px;

}
.progress-bar {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

/* Media queries */

@media(min-width:767px) {

    .navbar {
        padding: 20px 0;
        border-bottom: 0;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        background: 0 0;
        -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .top-nav-collapse {
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #000;
    }

    .navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse {
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    }
 
    .intro {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .brand-heading {
        font-size: 100px;
    }
 

    .intro-text {
        font-size: 25px;
    }


}
@media (max-width:768px) {
 #navigation {
  padding: 20px 0;
 }
 .site-logo{
  margin: 0 0 0 30px;
  float:none;
 }
 .navbar-custom ul.nav li a {
  color: #eee;
 }
 .navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;

 }
 .navbar-header {
  margin-top:-40px;
  padding:0;
 }
 .navbar-header button {
  background: #111;
 }
 
 .navbar-header button.navbar-toggle {
  padding: 4px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
 }
 
 .navbar-custom .nav {
  background: #444;
 }
 
 .service-box {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
 }
 
 .team-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
 }
 
 form#contact-form {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
 }
 
 .xs-marginbot-20 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 }

}

@media (max-width:480px) {

 .navbar-custom .nav.navbar-nav {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
 }
 
 .navbar.navbar-custom.navbar-fixed-top {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
 }
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-custom">

 <section class="hero" id="intro">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-right navicon">
     <a id="nav-toggle" class="nav_slide_button" href="#">
      <span></span>
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
     <img src="img/milogo2.png">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center inner">
     <div class="animatedParent">
      <h1 class="animated fadeInDown">Servicio de jardineria</h1>
      <p class="animated fadeInUp">Desbrozamos y limpiamos su finca.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
 </section>
 <div id="navigation">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom" role="navigation">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="site-logo">
    <img id="logo" src="http://i67.tinypic.com/2ufyhc8.jpg"/>     
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
       </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active">
         <a href="#intro">Casa</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#about">Sobre mi</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#service">Servicios</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#works">Trabajos</a>
        </li>

        <li>
         <a href="#contact">Contacto</a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </div>
 <section id="about" class="home-section color-dark bg-white">
  <div class="container marginbot-50">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
     <div class="animatedParent">
      <div class="section-heading text-center animated bounceInDown">
       <h2 class="h-bold">¿Quien somos...?</h2>
       <div class="divider-header"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 animatedParent">
     <div class="text-center">
      <p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vis tale malis tacimates et, graece doctus omnesque ne est, deserunt pertinacia ne nam. Pro eu
       simul affert referrentur, natum mutat erroribus te his
      </p>
      <p>
       Ne mundi fabulas corrumpit vim, nulla vivendum conceptam eu nam. Ius ex principes complectitur, ex quo duis suscipit. Ius
       fastidii reprimique no. Sadipscing appellantur pri ad. Oratio moderatius definitiones cum ex, mea ne brute vivendum
       percipitur.
      </p>
      <a href="#service" class="btn btn-skin btn-scroll">What we do</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section id="service" class="home-section color-dark bg-gray">
  <div class="container marginbot-50">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
     <div>
      <div class="section-heading text-center">
       <h2 class="h-bold">¿Què hacemos en Agrochema...?</h2>
       <div class="divider-header"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row animatedParent">
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <div class="animated rotateInDownLeft">
       <div class="service-box">
        <div class="service-icon">
         <span class="fa fa-laptop fa-7x"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="service-desc">
         <h5>Web Design</h5>
         <div class="divider-header"></div>
         <p>
          Ad denique euripidis signiferumque vim, iusto admodum quo cu. No tritani neglegentur mediocritatem duo.
         </p>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-skin">Learn more</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <div class="animated rotateInDownLeft slow">
       <div class="service-box">
        <div class="service-icon">
         <span class="fas fa-camera-retro fa-7x"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="service-desc">
         <h5>Photography</h5>
         <div class="divider-header"></div>
         <p>
          Ad denique euripidis signiferumque vim, iusto admodum quo cu. No tritani neglegentur mediocritatem duo.
         </p>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-skin">Learn more</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <div class="animated rotateInDownLeft slower">
       <div class="service-box">
        <div class="service-icon">
         <span class="fa fa-code fa-7x"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="service-desc">
         <h5>Graphic design</h5>
         <div class="divider-header"></div>
         <p>
          Ad denique euripidis signiferumque vim, iusto admodum quo cu. No tritani neglegentur mediocritatem duo.
         </p>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-skin">Learn more</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 
   <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] y edita tu pregunta en consecuencia. Para pedir ayuda con una imagen en la barra de navegación no deberían necesitarse las más de 1200 líneas de código que has compartido. Reduce el código del problema a lo mínimo para reproducirlo y ayuda a la gente a ayudarte.

Comment: Miguel no puedo ver donde esta el error, en tu código porque los estilos están incompletos, trata de quitar del html lo que no es necesario para el ejemplo, por ejemplo desde el "Quienes somos" hacia abajo, eso seguro te dejará meter más los estilos de *css* y apreciaríamos bien el error. Lo otro (y estoy adivinando), es que pruebes a sobrescribir o eliminar los padding del `navbar`, por lo regular es eso.

Comment: Gracias @EdgarGutiérrez El caso es que con esos estilos a mi me funciona en local, es el enlace a bootstrap lo que no debe funcionar bien, de echo te muestro el [ejemplo en Codepen](https://codepen.io/miguelitolaparra/pen/GQrvGV)con el mismo codigo, lo unico que no funciona es la barra de navegación pero eso ahora no importa, lo que me preocupa es que el logo ocupe todo el alto de la barra y no funciona ni con lo que el compañero Convinus 15 me sugirió.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He visto el codepen, yo únicamente forzaría al navbar que quite tanto el padding como el margin usando más especificidad así:

```
html nav.navbar.navbar-custom {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Trata de agregarlo a tu código y si no funciona, agregale un !important al final de cada propiedad.

Otro truco que puede funcionar son los márgenes negativos al logo, así:

```
#logo {
  margin-top: -0.8em !important;
  margin-bottom: -1.2em !important;
}
```

Evalúa con estas dos opciones y nos cuentas.

### Actualización

Cogi el codepen actualizado, resulta que no copiaste bien el selector que te pase del navbar (tenías clases separadas), mira, copia y pega y verás:

```css
/* ==== Google font ==== */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700,900);
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ek+Mukta:400,600,700');
*{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

/*==========================
SOLO VOY A MODIFICAR ESTAS
============================*/


#logo{
  /*background: url(../img/milogo2.png);*/
  padding: 0 ;
  margin: 0 ;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
} 

/*fijate que use el selector que te recomende*/
html nav.navbar.navbar-custom{
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
}

/*==========================
LO DE ABAJO NO LO TOQUE
============================*/


body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Ek Mukta', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
    color: #666;
    background-color: #fff;
 font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
 font-weight: 400;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 38px;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 36px;
}
h3 {
 font-size: 32px;
}
h4 {
 font-size: 28px;
}
h5 {
 font-size: 24px;
}
h6 {
 font-size: 20px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
 color: #111;
}

h1.h-xlight,h2.h-xlight,h3.h-xlight ,h4.h-xlight ,h5.h-xlight ,h6.h-xlight  {
 font-weight: 200;
}

h1.h-light,h2.h-light,h3.h-light ,h4.h-light ,h5.h-light ,h6.h-light  {
 font-weight: 300;
}

h1.h-bold,h2.h-bold,h3.h-bold ,h4.h-bold ,h5.h-bold ,h6.h-bold  {
 font-weight: 600;
}

h1.font-light,h2.font-light,h3.font-light,h4.font-light,h5.font-light,h6.font-light {
 color: #fff;
}

.big-heading {
 font-size: 48px;
 font-weight: 700;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 20px;

}

p.lead {
 font-weight: 600;
}

.highlight-light {
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
 padding: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 color: #111;
}

.highlight-dark {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 padding: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 color: #fff;
}

.highlight-color {
 padding: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
}

a {
    color: #666;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

blockquote {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #999;
}

blockquote.bg-light {
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
 padding: 20px;
 color: #222;
}

blockquote.bg-dark {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 padding: 20px;
}

blockquote strong {
  font-weight: 700;
}




.light {
    font-weight: 400;
}

/* --- logo --- */
.site-logo {
 display: flex;
 /*margin-top: 10px;*/
}
.site-logo a.brand {
 color: #111;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 32px;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 900;
 margin-top: 20px;
}


/* ------- Navigation ------------ */
#navigation {
 background: #fff;
 z-index: 9999;
 width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
 box-shadow:0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}


.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-weight: 700;
}


.navbar-brand:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.nav.navbar-nav {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse .nav.navbar-nav {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}


.navbar-custom ul.nav li a {
 font-size: 12px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #444;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse ul.nav li a {
     -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 color: #fff;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu {
   border-radius: 0; 
 margin-top: 21px;
 border-top: none;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav li a:hover ul.dropdown-menu {
     -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}


.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;

}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li:last-child{
 border-bottom: none;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a {
 padding: 10px 20px;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
 background: #fefefe;
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a {
 color: #666;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a {
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav li.active {
    outline: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav li.active {
    outline: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}

.navbar-toggle {
    padding: 4px 6px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-toggle:active {
    outline: 0;
}


/* misc */
hr {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

hr.bold {
  border-top: 3px solid #eee;
}

.divider-header {
 display: block;
 width: 40px;
 height: 2px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.divider-short {
 display: block;
 width: 60px;
 height: 5px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* margins */
.marginbot-0{margin-bottom:0 !important;}
.marginbot-10{margin-bottom:10px !important;}
.marginbot-20{margin-bottom:20px !important;}
.marginbot-30{margin-bottom:30px !important;}
.marginbot-40{margin-bottom:40px !important;}
.marginbot-50{margin-bottom:50px !important;}
.marginbot-60{margin-bottom:60px !important;}
.marginbot-70{margin-bottom:70px !important;}
.marginbot-80{margin-bottom:80px !important;}
.marginbot-90{margin-bottom:90px !important;}
.marginbot-100{margin-bottom:100px !important;}

.margintop-0{margin-top:0 !important;}
.margintop-10{margin-top:10px !important;}
.margintop-20{margin-top:20px !important;}
.margintop-30{margin-top:30px !important;}
.margintop-40{margin-top:40px !important;}
.margintop-45{margin-top:45px !important;}
.margintop-50{margin-top:50px !important;}

/* ===========================
--- General sections
============================ */

.home-section {
    padding-top: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 110px;
 display:block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:120;
}

.inner-section {
    padding-top: 110px;
    padding-bottom: 110px;
}


.home-section.nopadd-bot {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}


.section-heading h2 {
 font-size: 24px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.section-heading p {
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 1.6em;
}

.color-dark .section-heading h2 {
 color: #111;
}
.color-dark .section-heading p {
 color: #444;
}

.color-dark .divider-short {
 background: #666;
}
.color-dark .divider-header {
 background: #666;
}

.color-light .divider-short {
 background: #666;
}
.color-light .divider-header {
 background: #666;
}


.color-light .section-heading h2 {
 color: #fff;
}
.color-light .section-heading p {
 color: #fefefe;
}

.color-light blockquote,.color-light p {
 color: #fefefe;
}

/* --- section bg var --- */

.bg-white {
 background: #fff;
}

.bg-gray {
 background: #f9f9f9;
}


.bg-dark {
 background: #404040;
}

/* --- section color var --- */

.text-light {
 color: #fff;
}



/* ===========================
--- Intro
============================ */

.hero { background: url(http://i63.tinypic.com/vsgaon.jpg) no-repeat center center; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; padding: 200px 0 200px 0; height: auto; }
.hero h1 { font-size: 40px; letter-spacing: 12px; margin: 40px 0 10px; font-weight: 900; color: #fff;}
.hero h1 span { color: #a1a9b0; display: inline-block; }
.hero p { font-size: 24px; font-weight: 400; color: #fefefe; }
.learn-more-btn { background: rgba(61, 201, 179, 1); padding: 20px 40px; border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -o-border-radius: 5px; color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 1px; display: inline-block; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #309383; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #309383; box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #309383; margin: 60px 0 0; font-weight: bold; }
.learn-more-btn:hover, .learn-more-btn:focus { background: rgba(61, 201, 179, 0.6); color: #fff; }



.intro {
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 padding:0;
}
.intro-inner {
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 padding:120px 0 20px;
}

.brand-heading {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.intro-text {
    font-size: 18px;
}


/* Carousel Styles */

.carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 650px;
}

.carousel-control {
    width: 0;
}

.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right {
 opacity: 1;
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 background-image: none;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 text-shadow: none;
}

.carousel-control.left span {
 padding: 0;
}

.carousel-control.right span {
 padding: 0;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, 
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right, 
.carousel-control .icon-prev, 
.carousel-control .icon-next {
 position: absolute;
 top: 45%;
 z-index: 5;
 display: inline-block;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
.carousel-control .icon-prev {
 left: 30px;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right,
.carousel-control .icon-next {
 right: 30px;
}



.carousel-control.left span:hover,
.carousel-control.right span:hover {
 opacity: .7;
 filter: alpha(opacity=70);
}

.carousel-inner > .item {
  margin-left:0;
  margin-top:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left:0;
  padding-left: 0;
}


/* Carousel Header Styles */
.header-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 1.8%;
    right: auto;
    width: 96.66666666666666%;
    color: #fff;
}

.header-text h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.header-text h2 span {
 padding: 10px;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header-text h3 span {
 color: #fff;
}

.btn-min-block {
    min-width: 170px;
    line-height: 26px;
}

.btn-theme {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.btn-theme:hover {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
}

/* ===========================
--- About
============================ */




/* ===========================
--- Services
============================ */
.service-box {
 background: #fff;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #f7f7f7;
 padding: 40px 20px;
}

.service-box:hover {
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 margin-top: -20px;
}

.service-icon {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
} 

.service-desc h5 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #666;
 font-size: 18px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.service-desc .divider-header {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/* ===========================
--- Works
============================ */

#owl-works {

}

.item {
    margin: 10px;
}

.item img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
} 

/* ===========================
--- Contact
============================ */


.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

form#contact-form .form-group label {
 text-align: left !important;
 display: block;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 16px;
}
form#contact-form input,form#contact-form select,form#contact-form textarea {
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 1.6em;
 border: 1px solid #eee;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow:  none;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

.btn-lg,
.btn-group-lg > .btn {
  border-radius: 2px;
}

form#contact-form input:focus,form#contact-form select:focus,form#contact-form textarea:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
.input-group-addon {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

.widget-contact {
 text-align: left;
}



/* ===========================
--- Bottom
============================ */

.boxcol-25 {
 width: 100%;
}

.box-social {
 list-style: none;
}

.box-social li {
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
}


.box-social .social-facebook a { 
 display: block;
 background: #3873ae;
}


/* ==== Sidebar ==== */
.sidebar .widget h5 {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 700;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.sidebar .widget {
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.widget ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin-left:0;
 padding-left:0;
}
.sidebar .widget ul li {
 margin-left:0;
 padding-left:0;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.sidebar .widget ul li a {
 color: #666;
}


.widget.widget_categories ul li:before {
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: 'Pe-icon-7-stroke';
 speak: none;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 text-transform: none;
 line-height: 1;

 /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 content: "\e684";
 margin-right: 10px;
}


.widget.widget_recent_post ul li figure {
 float: left;
 margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.widget.widget_recent_post ul li {
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.widget.widget_recent_post ul li:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.widget.widget_recent_post ul li h6 {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.widget.widget_recent_post ul li span {
 font-size: 14px;
}

.widget .tagcloud a {
 padding: 4px 10px;
 color: #fff;
 display:inline-block;
 margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
 font-size: 14px;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

.widget .tagcloud a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 background: #333;
}

/* --- widget --- */

form.search-form input {
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 1.6em;
 border: 1px solid #eee;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow:  none;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

form.search-form input:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}



/* ===========================
--- Footer
============================ */

footer {
    background-color: #404040;
}

footer {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 50px 0 30px ;
 
}

footer p {
 color: #f8f8f8;
 font-size: 14px;
}

footer a.totop {
 color: #fff;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
footer a.totop:focus {
 outline: 0;
}



/* menu */
ul.footer-menu {
 list-style: none;
}

ul.footer-menu li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0 0 0 10px;

}

ul.footer-menu li a {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding-left: 9px;
 line-height: 1.1em;
}

ul.footer-menu li:first-child a {
 border-left: none;
 padding-left: 0;
}

.social-widget {
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.social-widget ul li a:hover {
 color: #fff;
}

footer .social-widget ul.team-social li a {
 margin: 0 5px;
}

/* === testimonial slide === */
.testimonialslide {
 margin-top:0;
 padding-top: 0;
}

.testimonialslide ul li blockquote {
 color: #fff;
 border-left: none;
}

.testimonialslide ul li h4 {
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 900;
}
.testimonialslide ul li h4 span {
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 400;
}


/* --- button --- */
.btn {
 border-radius: 2px;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 outline: none;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-weight: 400; 
 text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 font-size: 14px;
}

.btn.btn-noradius {
 border-radius: 0;
}

a.btn:focus{
 outline: 0;
}

.btn-red {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #c83539;
  border-color: #c83539;
}
.btn-red:hover,
.btn-red:focus,
.btn-red:active,
.btn-red.active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #666;
  border-color: #666;
}
.btn-red:active {
  background-image: none;
}


.btn-skin:hover,
.btn-skin:focus,
.btn-skin:active,
.btn-skin.active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #666;
  border-color: #666;
}


.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus {
    border: 1px solid #28c3ab;
    outline: 0;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #28c3ab;
}

.btn-huge {
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 26px;
}

.banner-social-buttons {
    margin-top: 0;
}

/* --- progress --- */
.progress {
  height: 40px;

}
.progress-bar {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

/* Media queries */

@media(min-width:767px) {

    .navbar {
        padding: 20px 0;
        border-bottom: 0;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        background: 0 0;
        -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .top-nav-collapse {
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #000;
    }

    .navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse {
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    }
 
    .intro {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .brand-heading {
        font-size: 100px;
    }
 

    .intro-text {
        font-size: 25px;
    }


}
@media (max-width:768px) {
 #navigation {
  padding: 20px 0;
 }
 .site-logo{
  margin: 0 0 0 30px;
  float:none;
 }
 .navbar-custom ul.nav li a {
  color: #eee;
 }
 .navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;

 }
 .navbar-header {
  margin-top:-40px;
  padding:0;
 }
 .navbar-header button {
  background: #111;
 }
 
 .navbar-header button.navbar-toggle {
  padding: 4px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
 }
 
 .navbar-custom .nav {
  background: #444;
 }
 
 .service-box {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
 }
 
 .team-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
 }
 
 form#contact-form {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
 }
 
 .xs-marginbot-20 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 }

}

@media (max-width:480px) {

 .navbar-custom .nav.navbar-nav {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
 }
 
 .navbar.navbar-custom.navbar-fixed-top {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
 }
}

.navbar .navbar-custom {
 padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias @Edgar Gutierrez , funciona con `#logo{
 padding: 0 ;
 margin: 0 ;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
 margin-top: -1.8em !important;
    margin-bottom: -2em !important;
  } 
`  .El problema es que solo se eliminó el padding de la parte de arriba, abajo del logo sigue. ¿ Que mas puedo hacer ?

Comment: Me quita el padding de arriba pero obliga al resto de botones hacia abajo, mira [como se ve en la captura.](http://prntscr.com/ic4avc) no se que mas revisar. Todo el dia llevo con ello...

Comment: Aqui [se ve mejor](http://prntscr.com/ic4dl1)

Comment: Y sigue pasando aunque incrementes más el margen de abajo en negativo, es decir algo así: `margin-bottom: -4em;`? Por cierto, tambien probaste con las dos opciones que te puse funcionando al tiempo? Si puedes actualiza también el codepen que compartiste con los ultimos cambios para ver si también se reproduce bien el error.

Comment: Sigue pasando, como veras en el [Codepen que actualice](https://codepen.io/miguelitolaparra/pen/GQrvGV), ya no se que hacer, lo peor es que me estancado aquí y no progreso con otras partes

Comment: Tuviste un error al copiar y pegar el selector que te pase, ahí te señalé en mi respuesta como corregirlo. Me avisas.

Comment: Gracias, sigue sin funcionar, en [Codepen tambien](https://codepen.io/miguelitolaparra/pen/GQrvGV)  lo cambie y tampoco      
Incluso si quito las medidas en negativo, [vuelve el padding de arriba](http://prntscr.com/ic8qco) .Vaya tela, @Edgar Gutiérrez , gracias por tu apoyo. Hay algo que no debe ir bien. No te conteste anoche porque ya me había acostado, eran las 2 de la madrugada y llevaba ya 15 horas delante del pc. Y sin resolver . A ver hoy.

Comment: No entiendo, acabo de revisar el pen y veo que los cambios si los toma ( [ver Pantallazo1](https://imgur.com/a/NJA2g)) incluso force el margen negativo para que el logo ocupe todavía más el alto y funciona ([ver Pantallazo 2](https://imgur.com/a/Nbhfp)). Si ves igual en tu pc o ¿No es que lo que querías lograr? Mira te dejo el [codepen con las modificaciones](https://codepen.io/g3kdigital/pen/LQWELd?editors=0100).

Comment: Eso es compañero, doy tu respuesta por buena, no se tendras que editarla.              Gracias @Edgar Gutiérrez .

Comment: Miguel, jajaja pero es que no tengo porque editarla, como te digo solo cogi los mismos estilos tal cual los tengo y los adapte a tu codigo, no se porque no te funcionaba a ti, bueno, lo importante es que ya se resolvió.

Answer (score 1):

Hola si lo que quieres es que el logo ocupe todo el alto del contenedor y que no te genere ninguna margen, primero debe quitar el `padding` que se genere en la clase `navbar navbar-custom`

```
.navbar navbar-custom{padding: 0;}
```

luego baja hasta la clase que contiene tu imagen, en este caso:

```
.site-logo{display: flex;}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias @Corvinus probe tu propuesta y no me funciona. Se lo muestro a Edgar Gutiérrez con un ejemplo en el comentario. Gracias por el apoyo